# How to share a viewMode Driver property for server views?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have a viewmode for login. And have a variable for sign result. I have another views will update there UI dependents on the result, like succes or fail.

At the begining, i wanna use the singleton mode for viewmode. But it's not recommanded. So how can i subscribe the same dirve varibale for many views.

```
var signupResult: Driver<LoginRepository> = Driver.empty()

signupResult = AladdinProvider.rx.request(.login(username: username, password: pwd)).filterSuccessfulStatusCodes().asObservable().mapObject(type: LoginRepository.self).asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: Driver.empty()).
```

Answer (score 0):

You subscribe to a driver by using the `drive` function.

```
let signupResult = AladdinProvider.rx
    .request(.login(username: username, password: pwd))
    .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
    .asObservable() // you likely don't need this operator
    .mapObject(type: LoginRepository.self)
    .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: Driver.empty())

signupResult
    .drive(onNext: { loginRepository in 
        // set up view for success here.
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

signupResult
    .drive(onNext: { loginRepository in 
        // set up different view for success here.
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: ```
// ViewMode
var signupResult: Driver<LoginRepository> = Driver.empty()
let signupResult = AladdinProvider.rx.request.....
```
```
// login view controller
let viewmode = ViewMode()
viewmode.signupResult
    .drive(onNext: { loginRepository in 
        // set up different view for success here.
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```
```
// other view or view controller
// TODO how to use the login view controller's  signupResult for the same instance?
```
Thanks.